# Как подсчитать количество проигрышей/выигрышей?

Tags: python

Написал программу, что при помощи генератора случайных чисел определяет победу/поражение, но не понимаю как произвести их подсчёт.

```
from colorama import init
init()
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from random import randint
two = randint(1, 2)
coungratulation = 'Поздравляю, вы выиграли!!!'
Loser = 'К сожалению вы проиграли!!!'
countLose = 0
countWin = 0
 
 
def func():
    if two == 2:
        print(Fore.GREEN ,coungratulation)
 
    elif two == 1:
        print(Fore.RED,Loser)
 
for i in range(10):
    
    two = randint(1, 2)
    func()
if two == 1:
    two = randint(1, 2)
    countLose + 1
 
elif two == 2:
    countWin + 1
 
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('Проигрышей:'+ str(countLose))
print('Выигрышей:'+ str(countWin))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from colorama import init
init()
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from random import randint
coungratulation = 'Поздравляю, вы выиграли!!!'
loser = 'К сожалению вы проиграли!!!'
countLose = 0
countWin = 0
 
for i in range(10):
    two = randint(1, 2)
    if two == 1:
        countLose += 1
        print(Fore.RED, loser)
    else:
        countWin += 1
        print(Fore.GREEN, coungratulation)
 
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('Проигрышей:'+ str(countLose))
print('Выигрышей:'+ str(countWin))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием функции, как это задумывалось изначально:

```
# Инициализация библиотек
from colorama import Fore, Style
from random import randint

# Глобальные переменные
coungratulation = 'Поздравляем, вы выиграли!'
loser = 'К сожалению вы проиграли!'
countLose, countWin = 0, 0


# Функция подсчета и печати результатов
def func():
    global countWin, countLose  # Объявляем переменные глобальными для возможности их изменения внутри функции
    if two:
        print(Fore.GREEN, coungratulation)
        countWin += 1
    else:
        print(Fore.RED, loser)
        countLose += 1


for i in range(10):
    two = randint(0, 1)
    func()

print(Style.RESET_ALL, end='')  # Сбрасываем настройки стиля шрифта, не пропуская строку при печати
print(f'Проигрышей: {countLose}')
print(f'Выигрышей: {countWin}')
```